# Why don't the checkboxes get unchecked when I loop and uncheck them using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have created a table dynamically using jquery and it has a checkbox **chkBoxSelected**

I am looping through only rows which are checked. After posting them via ajax I want to uncheck the boxes but it only does the first one and not others.

```
 $('#chkBoxSelected').prop("checked", false).filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');
```

Full Code:

Table:

```
<table id="tblServices" class="table table-responsive ">
      <thead class="table-header">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                    <th>Service Name</th>
                                    <th>Service Price</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbodytblServices" class="tableBody"></tbody>

                        </table>
```

Table generation code:

```
 function fillServicesGrid() {

            var url = '@Url.Action("GetServices")';
            var data = ''

            $.get(url, data, function (response) {

                $("#tbodytblServices").html("");

                $.each(response, function (i, val) {

                    $("#tbodytblServices").append($('<tr>').attr('id', 'trServiceRecord').append($('<td>').attr('id', "tdServiceID" + i).html(val.ServiceID)).append($('<td>').attr('id', "tdServiceName" + i).html(val.ServiceName)).append($('<td>').attr('id', "tdServicePrice" + i).html(val.ServicePrice)).append($('<input type="checkbox" class="selectColumn" id="chkBoxSelected" />')));

                });

            });



        }
```

Data submission:

```
 function selectService() {

        var i = 0;

        $("#tblServices tr").filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function () {

            i = 1; // to check if the looping has been done or not

            var url = '@Url.Action("CreateInvoice")';
            var data = { fk_BookingID: $("#Booking_ID").val(), fk_ServiceID: $("td:eq(0)", this).text() }

            $.post(url, data, function (response)
            {
                if (response.ReturnStatusJSON === true) {                       

                    swal("Done", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "success");
                }
                else
                {
                    swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
                }


            });




        });
```

Comment: I do not see where you uncheck them in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `checkboxes` with `class` not `id`. `#chkBoxSelected` is an `ID` and it's unique and used for one, so should use class for select all checkboxes.

```js
$('.selectColumn').prop("checked", false).filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectColumn" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectColumn" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectColumn" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectColumn" checked/>
```

And also note that, you should generate unique `ID` for each `checkbox` to avoid duplicate `ID`